# Simulate network problems within an android emulator

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, connection

I would like to simulate some network problems with the emulator. I know that pressing f8 I can disable the network but, as a result, I lost the connection with eclipse, the adb and the debug session!

Furthermore, I can not test the case where a server may not work well while the network is ok, or other similar network problems.

Comment: What kind of network problems do you want to simulate?

Answer (score 3):

Install GenyMotion

Setup a VM of a tablet

Use this via Eclipse

Then in the VM

Settings
WiFi OFF

Works a dream , just tried it

Phil

Comment: GenyMotion is impressive!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`telnet`** to get access to the Android Console within the emulator, and from there you can affect [speed](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netspeed) and [latency](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#netdelay) of the emulated network connection.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to simulate network disconnection, url unreachable and so on

Comment: @AlfonsoSparano: You can try the `network status` Console command for network disconnection. "URL unreachable" has no specific meaning that I am aware of.

Comment: url unreachable mean that I would like to test at least two servers. Server A must be unreachable meanwhile Server B should be reachable

Comment: @AlfonsoSparano: You will do that yourself by programming, or perhaps via some sort of proxy server.